# Google Maps - Drawing the route without the markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am drawing a route for two points using Google Maps API but I have some inconvenient from this drawing. When I draw the route, Google it shows me on map two points, A and B, the origin and destination point.

The problem is that I can't take it out. I need to show only the route without this markers.

Have someone known how to show only the route?

The code is based on example from developers guide
https://plnkr.co/edit/UWfKc7XGHtdbeRZkUS8X?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Directions service (complex)</title>
        <style>
            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
             * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var startLatLng;
            var endLatLng;
            var startAddr = 'Grand Central Station';
            var endAddr = 'City Hall';

            function initMap() {
                // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: {lat: 40.771, lng: -73.974}
                });

                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
                calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService);
            }

            function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService) {
                // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using DRIVING directions.
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: startAddr,
                    destination: endAddr,
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                }, function(response, status) {
                    // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create markers for each step.
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        console.log(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCgkOZvjHinGyRsQT7WO1R7KGmtxJJfDPE&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can provide options when initializing the map to hide markers. Otherwise have a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove?hl=de

Comment: I know how to hide/delete some markers but the problem is that I don't know where I find this two markers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true});
```

And here the link to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions) where all the options are explained